# NativeControls and Device Orientation

Tags: cordova, device-orientation

I'm using the NativeControls plugin and a native footerbar in my PhoneGap iOS app.

When I rotate my iPhone, the footerbar also rotates but it only shows a black bar without any icon... And when I move to another page, the whole interface is completely broken and I need to restart the app.

Does anyone know how to solve it? Maybe the NativeControls plugin is not compatible with landscape orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Support for device rotation was never really implemented.
Here are the steps:

1) add the orientation listener:

```js
document.addEventListener("orientationChanged",redrawTabBar,false);
```

2) add the function called when there is an orientation change:

```js
function redrawTabBar() {
    if (navigator.notification){
        PhoneGap.exec("NativeControls.redrawTabBar");
    }
}
```

3) add the method in the actual plugin (.m):

```objective-c
- (void)redrawTabBar:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options
{
    tabBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, self.webView.frame.size.height, self.webView.frame.size.width, 50);
}
```

4) make sure the orientationChanged event is fired by the webview. Inside MainViewcontroller.m

```objective-c
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
int i = 0;  
    switch (self.interfaceOrientation){
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            i = 0;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            i = 180;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            i = -90;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            i = 90;
            break;
    }

    NSString* jsString = 
    @"(function(){"
    "var e = document.createEvent('Events');"
    "e.initEvent('orientationChanged');"
    "document.dispatchEvent(e);"
    "})();";
    NSLog(@"Orientation Changed");
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
```

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. However, I don't seem to have a MainViewcontroller.m file. Could you clarify that piece??